# I make display nav bar menu. Why do I have to get id for list?

Tags: javascript

I make display nav bar menu. According to the lesson, I have to get id for list (code: list.id = section.id) in javascript? Why? https://github.com/Loc1111/Udacity_Landing-Page

```js
const navbarMenu = document.getElementById('navbar__list');
const sections = document.getElementsByTagName('section');

for(section of sections){
  const list = document.createElement('li');
  list.id = section.id;
  list.innerText = section.dataset.nav;
  list.classList.add('menu__link');
  navbarMenu.appendChild(list);
}
```

```css
.navbar__menu .menu__link {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">    
    <body>        
        <header class="page__header">
            <nav class="navbar__menu">                
                <ul id="navbar__list"></ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
            <header class="main__hero">
                <h1>Landing Page </h1>
            </header>          
            <section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="your-active-class">                
            </section>
            <section id="section2" data-nav="Section 2">                
            </section>
            <section id="section3" data-nav="Section 3">                
            </section>
            <section id="section4" data-nav="Section 4">                
            </section>     
        </main>       
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Because it tells you so. It makes HTML invalid with non-unique ID's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't have two identical ids

you need to add href link to the section

```js
const navbarMenu = document.getElementById('navbar__list');
const sections = document.getElementsByTagName('section');

for(section of sections){
  const list = document.createElement('li');
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = '#' + section.id;
  a.innerText = section.dataset.nav;
  list.appendChild(a);
  list.classList.add('menu__link');
  navbarMenu.appendChild(list);
}
```

```css
.navbar__menu .menu__link {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">    
    <body>        
        <header class="page__header">
            <nav class="navbar__menu">                
                <ul id="navbar__list"></ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
            <header class="main__hero">
                <h1>Landing Page </h1>
            </header>          
            <section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="your-active-class">                
            </section>
            <section id="section2" data-nav="Section 2">                
            </section>
            <section id="section3" data-nav="Section 3">                
            </section>
            <section id="section4" data-nav="Section 4">                
            </section>     
        </main>       
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question is these code above are correct. It is in the lesson. But I don't understand why I have to embed the code: list.id = section.id;

Comment: this doesn't make any sense. this line of code is wrong. you don't need to embed this line of code because the results of this line will make duplicated elements ids